# express number series in puppet

Tags: puppet

I want to create folders like below:

/opt/data/APP/app01...../opt/data/APP/app10

How do i express this puppet, is the below correct?

```
file { [ '/opt/data','/opt/data/APP',"/opt/data/APP/app[01-10]" ]:
   ensure  => directory,
   owner   => 'appowner',
   group   => 'appgroup',
   mode    => '750',
}
```

Comment: Correct: `[01-10]` to `\d+`

Comment: what does "\d+" mean and where do i put this

Comment: `\d` means a digits. `+` means at least one of the last char.

Comment: This has nothing to do with regex, and really is about how to emulate Bash brace expansion in Puppet.

Answer (score 3):

### Latest Puppet

The [`range()`](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#functions) function from stdlib combined with the built-in [`flatten`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#flatten) function is a perfect fit for this problem. Try this:

```puppet
$dirs = flatten([
  '/opt/data',
  '/opt/data/APP',
  range('/opt/data/APP/app01', '/opt/data/APP/app10') 
])

file { $dirs:
  ensure  => directory,
  owner   => 'appowner',
  group   => 'appgroup',
  mode    => '750',
}
```

Testing:

```
▶ puppet apply test.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for redacted in environment production in 0.02 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/data]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/data/APP]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/data/APP/app01]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/data/APP/app02]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/data/APP/app03]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/data/APP/app04]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/data/APP/app05]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/data/APP/app06]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/data/APP/app07]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/data/APP/app08]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/data/APP/app09]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/opt/data/APP/app10]/ensure: created
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.03 seconds
```

Strictly speaking, `flatten()` isn't required there, since the array of arrays will be auto-flattened in the context of the [array of titles](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_resources_advanced.html#arrays-of-titles). This behaviour appears to be undocumented.

Personally, I would include it anyway for the sake of clarity and readability.

### Puppet 3

If you have an earlier Puppet such as Puppet 3, however, you would need to explicitly include stdlib, and there would be no `flatten()` function. Thus you could write this:

```puppet
include stdlib

$dirs = [
  '/opt/data',
  '/opt/data/APP',
  range('/opt/data/APP/app01', '/opt/data/APP/app10')
]

file { $dirs:
  ensure  => directory,
  mode    => '750',
}
```

Comment: Could `Integer[0, 9]` be used at all here without increasing complexity? I would guess not.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I think so, and then iterate? I was going to do that myself until I realised the range function seems to do everything the OP wants.

Comment: Is it application for puppet 3.8

Comment: @user973430, I have updated with a Puppet 3 solution.